# python loops very slow

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy

I have a question concerning the speed of loops in Python.
I created the following loops to fill values in my array, but it is very slow.
Is there a way to make it process faster ?

```
winW = 1    
winH = 200    
runlength = np.zeros(shape=(img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))


for y in range(0, img.shape[0] - winH, 1):
   for x in range(0, img.shape[1] - winW, 1):
      runlength[y, x] += np.sum(img[y:y + winH, x:x + winW]) / (winH * winW)
      runlength[y + winH, x] += np.sum(img[y:y + winH, x:x + winW]) / (winH * winW)
```

Thanks for your help

Edit : I precise that I can only use numpy but not scipy

Comment: If your code runs without errors and produces the expected output, it might be more appropriate to ask on [codereview.se]. Code optimization is explicitly on topic there.

Comment: @Mar: is winW constantly 1??

Comment: You can try to use Numba of Cython for loops speedup, not shure it will much help, but who knows.

Comment: @blue_note Yes winW is always 1

Comment: @usr2564301, this sort of 'vectorization' is one of the most common questions for `numpy` on SO.  CR answers tend to focus more on style.  But if you are an active CR participant with an answer to contribute ...

Answer (score 2):

Let me describe how to speed up the first operation in the for loop, given by

```
runlength[y, x] += np.sum(img[y:y + winH, x:x + winW]) / (winH * winW)
```

Basically, you are moving a rectangle of width `winW` and height `winH` over the image. You start with the upper-left corner of the rectangle at point (0,0) of the image, then you sum all values in the image which lie below this rectangle and divide them by the total number of points. The output at position (0,0) is that number. Then you shift the rectangle one to the right and repeat the procedure until you are at the right end of the image. You move one row down and repeat.

In image processing terms: you apply a spatial filter mask to the image. The filter is an average filter of width `winW` and height `winH`.

To implement this efficiently, you can use the [`scipy.ndimage.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.correlate.html) function. The `input` is your image, the `weights` contains the weight by which element below the rectangle is multiplied. In this case that is an array with dimensions `(winH, winW)` where every element contains the number `1 / (winH * winW)`. Thus every point of the image which lies below the rectangle is multiplied by `1 / (winH * winW)`, and then everything is summed.

To match your algorithm exactly, we need to set the `origin` to `(-np.floor(winH/2), -np.floor(winW/2))` to specify that the mean of the rectangle is placed at the location upper right corner of the rectangle in the output.

Finally, to match your algorithm exactly, we have to set all points below `(img.shape[0] - winH)` or right of `(img.shape[1] - winW)` to zero. The for-loop can thus be replaced with

```
runlength_corr = correlate(input=img,
                           weights=np.ones((winH, winW)) / (winW * winH),
                           origin=(-np.floor(winH/2), -np.floor(winW/2)))
runlength_corr[(img.shape[0] - winH):, :] = 0
runlength_corr[:, (img.shape[1] - winW):] = 0
```

I compared the run time of the nested for-loops and the `correlate` method on a test image of size 512-by-512:

```
For-loops: Elapsed time: 0.665 sec
Correlate: Elapsed time: 0.085 sec
```

So this gives a nice speed-up of factor 8. The sum of absolute differences over the entire output is as low as `7.04e-09`, so the outputs of both methods are essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you very much hbaderts for this precise answer. The problem (important and that I forgot to write) is that I can't use scipy for my problem (so I can't use convolution functions), only numpy.

Comment: Oh okay. As long as `winW` is 1, you could maybe use [`np.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you seem to be calculating the same quantity twice, inside you loop. That alone could half your running time.

Second, if `winW` is always `1`, then `np.sum(img[y:y + winH, x:x + winW])` is just
`np.sum(img[y:y + winH, x])`. That should speed it up a bit.

What remains is how you can speed up `np.sum(img[y:y + winH, x])`. You can start with calculating

```
sum0 = np.sum(img[0: 0 + winH, x])
```

Now, note that the quantity

```
sum1 = np.sum(img[1: 1 + winH, x])
```

differs from the previous one by two pixels only, so, it is equal to `sum0 - img[0, x] + img[1 + winH, x]`. For the next `y`

```
sum2 = sum1 - img[1, x] + img[2 + winH, x]`
```

and so on